# ExpectedConditions.or function not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have to test an e-shop. The users can add items to their cart.
When the cart is empty, a special section with id "empty-basket" is created. If the cart is not empty, this section's id becomes "basket".

I use Java and Selenium 3.9

These are my two selectors

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "#empty-basket > section")
private WebElement conteneur_panier_vide;

@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "#basket > section:nth-child(1)")
private WebElement conteneur_panier_non_vide;
```

To check if the bloc containing the elements is well formed, I check if there is one of the sections described above. I use this piece of code to do so:

```
this.wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.or(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(conteneur_panier_vide),
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(conteneur_panier_non_vide)
    )
);
```

However, this gives me an error

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for at least one condition to be
>   valid

Surprised, I tried this:

```
this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(conteneur_panier_vide))
```

on a page with an empty basket. It works, the WebElement is found.

I then tried this:

```
this.wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.or(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(conteneur_panier_vide),
    )
);
```

And it works as well. It means that adding a non-existing element to the 'or' breaks it, which is exactly the opposite of what it should be.

Does anyone have an idea of why my code is not working?

---

Edit: SOLVED!

The problem was that the element I was looking for was not on the page when the `or` function is called, resulting in the malfunctioning mentioned above.

I simply put

```
this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains(MY_CART_URL));
```

which ensures the presence of one of the two sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can do to clean this up:

1. Create a CSS selector that matches both elements
2. Use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.css(...))` instead of the more complicated `or`

```java
// CSS selectors can be separated by a comma (,)
String cssSelector = "#empty-basket > section, #basket > section:nth-child(1)";

this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(cssSelector));
```

Your original problem was that using the `conteneur_panier_vide` and `conteneur_panier_non_vide` attributes was causing Selenium to attempt to fetch them. You just need to wait for the appearance of either element.

Comment: Your method works, but there is a little typo:
`this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.css(cssSelector));`
should be
`this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)));`

Comment: @SzmaKS: Good catch. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you instantiated your wait object? You didn't specify your environment but here's what I do in

**C#**
`var wait   = new WebDriverWait( Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 10 ) );`

**Java**
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);`

Comment: Hi, yes my WebDriverWait object is instantiated with a 10s timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem, and edited the question to let people know.

TL;DR:
I needed some delay before calling the `or` function, and did so by waiting for the URL to be the right one.